# Is this an error? Why is the probability 2/9 for returning to starting position?

Tags: combinatorics, markov-process

From [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/150/takis_exercises.pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/150/takis_exercises.pdf) page 24

Consider a triangle with the verticies 1, 2,3

and transition rules:

$p_{12}=p_{23}=p_{31}= 2/3$,  $p_{21}=p_{32}=p_{13}= 1/3$

I am assuming the process begins (n=0) at 1, so hence the p=1

Then it can go from 1 to 2 or from 1 to 3, as denoted below, so the odds of it staying on 1 for (n=1) are zero.

(1,3)

(1,2)

For n=2, we have all the possible paths and probabilities:

(1,2,3)  4/9

(1,2,1)  2/9

(1,3,1)  2/9

(1,3,2)  1/9

So for n=2 (superscript p_2) the odds of returning to the start should be 4/9 instead of 2/9?

$2/9=p^2_{11}=C_1x^2_1+C_2x^2_2+C_3x^2_3$

Comment: Your observation looks right.

Comment: It looks like it is just a typo.  Note that the formula they provide for $p_{11}^{(n)}$ evaluates to $\frac 49$ at $n=2$.